# Get Html Input Text Value to JavaScript Using Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I am trying out a given example of meteor server installation.In this Example everything is fine But i have added one new input field.How to **get This input text value in JavaScript using Meteor template**.I Didn't get any idea about this so please help me.

Html Code:

```
<head>
  <title>myapp</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{greeting}} <br>
  First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

Js Code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient)
 {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () 
  {
    return "Welcome to myapp.";
  };



  Template.hello.events
  ({
    'click input' : function ()
    {    
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
        if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
        alert("firstName="+ //here get input text value);

    }
  });
}



if (Meteor.isServer) 
{
  Meteor.startup(function ()
  {
    // code to run on server at startup
     console.log("Is Running Server");
  });
}
```

Comment: This works fine for me.  Are you not seeing "You pressed the button" printed out in the js console?

Comment: This also works fine for me, there is no reason for it not to work.

Comment: Really,But this is not work for me.so what mistake i can do?.@go-oleg

Comment: Do you see any errors in your js console?

Comment: No errors found.Is printed out client & server messages is same console?.@go-oleg

Comment: No, server messages are printed out in terminal where you started meteor.  The client messages are printed out in the browser's JavaScript console.  In Chrome you can open it through View -> Developer -> JavaScript Console.

Answer (score 0):

inside your client. you should return false

```
 Template.hello.events
  ({
    'click input' : function ()
    {    
        console.log("You pressed the button");
        return false;

    }
  });
```

Comment: This is also not executed.@pahan.

Comment: @Venkat this does work. Maybe you're not looking at the javascript console. Change `console.log` to `alert` if you want it as a message box instead